# Choppy wifi, most likely due to locationd errors

Tags: network, wifi, high-sierra

I am having a problem with choppy wifi. My main question is how can I troubleshoot this problem? I am using new MBP Mid 2015 - newest OSX 10.13. A few days after a restart of the machine the pings slow down. More precisely they slow down to 1 second every 10 seconds:

```
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1664 ttl=54 time=37.665 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1665 ttl=54 time=18.553 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1666 ttl=54 time=62.625 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1667 ttl=54 time=21.441 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1668 ttl=54 time=856.783 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1669 ttl=54 time=1125.355 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1670 ttl=54 time=855.837 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1671 ttl=54 time=600.021 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1672 ttl=54 time=17.359 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1673 ttl=54 time=18.438 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1674 ttl=54 time=17.940 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1675 ttl=54 time=21.492 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1676 ttl=54 time=20.422 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1677 ttl=54 time=22.927 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1678 ttl=54 time=21.628 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1679 ttl=54 time=14.896 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1680 ttl=54 time=557.451 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1682
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1682 ttl=54 time=1307.316 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1683 ttl=54 time=324.678 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1684 ttl=54 time=20.069 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1685 ttl=54 time=21.605 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1686 ttl=54 time=16.481 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.215.99: icmp_seq=1687 ttl=54 time=20.432 ms
```

This happens on different wifi networks (home, work, family), both when there are 50 wifi networks detected (home), and just 5 or so (work). Console logs show a few wifi-related messages:

```
default 19:20:18.869014 +0200   wirelessproxd   client.trigger:#N Random sample for 0x28000d is skip
default 19:20:18.972781 +0200   locationd   WIFI_LOC: onNetworkLocationNotification, <private>, kNotificationQueryResponseFinishedWifis, scanAge, <private>, interval, <private>, tag, <private>, aps, <private>
default 19:20:18.973472 +0200   locationd   queryLocations, g, <private>, s, <private>, c, <private>, l, <private>, w, <private>, cache, <private>, piggyWifis, <private>, piggyCells, <private>
default 19:20:18.973674 +0200   locationd   WIFI_LOC: processScanResult, aps, <private>, fIsUseNetworkLocationProvider, <private>, fIsUseTileManager, <private>
default 19:20:18.981688 +0200   locationd   WIFI_LOC: calculator result, <private>, aps, <private>, index, <private>, confidence, <private>, location, <private>
default 19:20:18.981715 +0200   locationd   WIFI_LOC: result, ReachRssi, <private>, locationReachRssi, <private>, emergency, <private>, <private>
default 19:20:18.981891 +0200   locationd   WIFI_LOC: isStopCriteriaSatisfied, numOfAPsInSolution, <private>, desiredAccuracy, <private>, isStop, <private>, currentRequest, <private>, loc, <private>
default 19:20:18.981992 +0200   locationd   WIFI_LOC: knownCount, <private>, unknownCount, <private>, knownCountTile, <private>, knownToUnknownRatio, <private>, queryMacAddresses.size, <private>, sinceLastServerQuery, <private>, isQueryNeeded, <private>, inject, <private>, forceQuery, <private>, queryType, <private>, reqType, <private>
default 19:20:18.983053 +0200   locationd   {"msg":"Sending location to client", "clientName":""}
default 19:20:18.983464 +0200   locationd   {"msg":"Sending location to client", "clientName":""}
fault   19:20:18.983964 +0200   navd    Discarding message for event 0 because of too many unprocessed messages
```

(Last line is really "fault" not "default" - it has a red dot next to it). My issue is almost exacly the same as here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8280552
however the "Apple recommended" answer is completely useless (does not work, plus I am unwilling to kick all saved networks - I tried that but it did not help and I have restored my full list from Time Machine).

As described there cable connection works fine for me as well.

Comment: Have you tried in Safe Mode to see if something is conflicting?

Comment: I will try it. However I do not have non-apple kernel extensions.

Comment: I wrote i do NOT have them.

Comment: My mistake...I read that incorrectly.   Though, my suggestion is not about kexts per se.

Comment: I will check it, however given the issue appear one or two days after a restart it will take some time to check.

Comment: I have checked in safe mode: the problem is not there, but in normal mode after a restart it is also not there. I am getting back to safe more and I will try to survive there for few days... (as it turns out I am able to work there, just have to mention that it feels like Linux days all over again).

Comment: If you're trying to diagnose a wifi issue I'd recommend pinging a device on the local network, like the router you're connecting via. That will take the internet and any external latency out of the equation.

Comment: The other thing you want to try is to create another user account and test there as well.  This way you will narrow it down to either systemwide or user account issue

Comment: If I ping the router the result is exactly the same (I have checked that before), but its a good suggestion I will ping my router instead. Ok I like that suggestion. I will also be more specific: after the restart the high ping is gone, also those WIFI_LOC messages are gone. I guess now a few days of trial and error await me :)

Comment: @Allan In safe mode it appears not to happen. At least it did not appear in 2 days. In normal mode it appears on a brand-new account.